# Read and Write a file from Apex to an FTP location

Tags: apex

We need to read and write a file from Apex to an FTP location. Is this feasible or if anybody has come across / implemented similar requirement.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't access FTP directly through Apex Code. You could access FTP through a SOAP or REST FTP proxy bridge, though. I was planning on writing a free one myself, but I got caught up in trying to implement SOAP in PHP, but it should conceptually be easy to implement.

Comment: Can you please provide some link where i can find more about SOAP or REST FTP proxy bridge?

Answer (score -4):

Yes, we've done it.

To do it in an automated way, check out the free jitterbit loader.

That way you're covered if you need any basic transformations, too.

Comment: That's not Apex Code...